# Active Navigation Bar section

Tags: javascript, html, css, nav

I am trying to make a website for my f1 in schools team and I want to know how I can make a button in my nav bar change bg and font color when I am on that part of the page even with scrolling and clicking on the button. If I am right I need CSS and JS right??
I need help only in the navbar else my website is completely responsive and perfect according to me.

HTML

```
<html>
<button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Back to top">Back to Top</button>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<div class="main">
<head>
    <title>Night Wolves</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source Sans Pro">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body class="w3-light-white w3-margin">
    <!-- Navigation bar -->
    <nav class="navbar" id="thebar" style="position: relative; top: -1px; position: sticky;">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="logo">
                <a style="position: relative; top: -7px;" href="#Home">Night Wolves</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="menu-list">
                <div class="icon cancel-btn">
                    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                </div>
                <li><a class="btn" href="#Home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="btn active" href="#Members">Members</a></li>
                <li><a class="btn" href="#About us">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a class="btn" href="#Portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a class="btn" href="#Contact us">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="icon menu-btn">
                <i class="fas fa-bars" style="position: relative; right: -10px; top: -6px;"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="w3-content" style="max-width:1500px">
    <!-- Image and background with title -->
    <header class="w3-display-container w3-wide" style="padding-bottom:32px;" id="Home">
        <img class="w3-image"
            src="F1CarBG.png"
            alt="Photo by Jamie Street" width="1600" height="1060">
        <div class="w3-display-left w3-padding-large">
            <h1 class="F1teamtext"><b style="font-size: 6vw; color: #8B008B;">F1 TEAM</b></h1>
            <h1 class="nightwolvestext"><b style="color: yellow; font-size: 6vw;">NIGHT
                WOLVES</b>
            </h1>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!-- Members -->
    <div class="w3-row-padding" id="Members">
        <div class="w3-center w3-padding-32">
            <h2 style="color: yellow; position: relative; bottom: -40px;" ,class="w3-wide w3-center">MEMBERS</h2>
            <p style="color: yellow; position: relative; bottom: -40px;" ,class="w3-opacity w3-center"><i>"There is no 'I' in team."</i></p>
            <br>
            <p class="w3-white w3-text-black w3-left-align">
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-third w3-margin-bottom" id="Arnav">
            <div class="w3-card-4" style="position: relative; left: -15px;">
                <div class="w3-container">
                    <h3 style="color: white; position: relative; bottom: -5px;">Arnav</h3>
                    <p style="color: white;" ,class="w3-opacity">Marketing Manager</p>
                    <p> </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-third w3-margin-bottom">
            <div class="w3-card-4">
                <div class="w3-container">
                    <h3 style="color: white; position: relative; bottom: -5px;">Kevin</h3>
                    <p style="color: white;" ,class="w3-opacity">Team Manager</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-third w3-margin-bottom">
            <div class="w3-card-4" style="position: relative; right: -10px;">
                <div class="w3-container">
                    <h3 style="color: white; position: relative; bottom: -5px;">Chislon</h3>
                    <p style="color: white;" ,class="w3-opacity">Resource Manager</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-third w3-margin-bottom">
        <div class="w3-card-4">
            <div class="w3-container">
                <h3 style="color: white; position: relative; bottom: -5px;">Kiran</h3>
                <p style="color: white;" ,class="w3-opacity">Manufacturing Engineer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-third w3-margin-bottom">
        <div class="w3-card-4" style="position: relative; right: -5px;">
            <div class="w3-container">
                <h3 style="color: white; position: relative; bottom: -5px;">Aaron</h3>
                <p style="color: white;" ,class="w3-opacity">Design Engineer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-third w3-margin-bottom">
        <div class="w3-card-4" style="position: relative; right: -10px;">
            <div class="w3-container">
                <h3 style="color: white; position: relative; bottom: -5px;">Fadil</h3>
                <p style="color: white;" ,class="w3-opacity">Graphic Designer</p>
                <p> </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- About Us-->
    <div class="w3-row-padding" id="About us">
    <div class="w3-center w3-padding-32">
    <h2 style="color: yellow;" ,class="w3-wide w3-center">ABOUT US</h2>
    <p class="w3-white w3-text-black w3-left-align">
    </p>
    <p style="font-size: 30px; color: white; text-align: center; font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;"> We are the Night Wolves</p>
    <p style="font-size: 30px; color: white; text-align: center; font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;"> This is our team of 6 racers Kevin, Arnav,
        Chislon,
        Fadil, 
        <br>
        Aaron
        and Kiran.
    </p>
    <p style="font-size: 30px; color: white; text-align: center; font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;">We will never give up in the field of
        racing.
    </p>
    <!-- Portfolio -->
    <div style="position: relative; bottom: -400px;" class="w3-row-padding" id="Portfolio">
    <div class="w3-center w3-padding-32">
    <div style="position: relative; top: -350px;">
        <h2 style="color: yellow; text-align: top;" ,class="w3-wide w3-center">PORTFOLIO</h2>
        <p class="w3-white w3-text-black w3-left-align">
    </div>
    </p>
    <!-- Contact us-->      
    <div class="w3-row-padding" id="Contact us">
    <div class="w3-center w3-padding-32">
        <h2 style="color: yellow;" ,class="w3-wide w3-center">CONTACT US!</h2>
        <!doctype html>
        <html lang="en" style="background-color: #5518AB;">
            <head style="background-color: #5518AB;">
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
            </head>
            <body style="background-color: #5518AB;">
                <div class="container mt-5" style="background-color: #5518AB;">
                    <form class="row g-3" action="https://formsubmit.co/a19d9c2e5e9b57c704f25be5e736c312" method="POST">
                        <input type="text" name="_honey" style="display: none;">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_captcha" value="false">
                        <div class="col-md-6" style="color: white;">
                            <label for="firstName" class="form-label">First Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="firstName" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6" style="color: white;">
                            <label for="lastName" class="form-label">Last Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Last&nbsp;Name" id="lastName" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8" style="color: white;">
                            <label for="emailInfo" class="form-label">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="emailInfo" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12" style="color: white;">
                            <label for="comments" class="form-label">Comments, questions?</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments,&nbsp;questions" rows="3" required></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12" style="color: white;">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->
                <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
                <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
                <!--
                    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Atwg2Pkwv9vp0ygtn1JAojH0nYbwNJLPhwyoVbhoPwBhjQPR5VtM2+xf0Uwh9KtT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                    -->
                <button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top"> Back to Top</button>
            </body>
        </html>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var x = document.getElementById("demo");
                if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
                    x.className += " w3-show";
                } else {
                    x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
                }
            }
            const body = document.querySelector("body");
            const navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar");
            const menuBtn = document.querySelector(".menu-btn");
            const cancelBtn = document.querySelector(".cancel-btn");
            menuBtn.onclick = ()=>{
            navbar.classList.add("show");
            menuBtn.classList.add("hide");
            body.classList.add("disabled");
            }
            cancelBtn.onclick = ()=>{
            body.classList.remove("disabled");
            navbar.classList.remove("show");
            menuBtn.classList.remove("hide");
            }
            window.onscroll = ()=>{
            this.scrollY > 20 ? navbar.classList.add("sticky") : navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
            }
            // Get the button:
            let mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");
            
            // When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
            window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};
            
            function scrollFunction() {
            if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
            mybutton.style.display = "block";
            } else {
            mybutton.style.display = "none";
            }
            }
            
            // When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
            function topFunction() {
            document.body.scrollTop = 0; // For Safari
            document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; // For Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera
            }
        </script>
</body>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
/* custom scroll bar */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #5518Ab;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: yellow;
}
::selection{
  background: yellow;
}
.content{
  max-width: 1250px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
}
.navbar{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 25px 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  background: yellow;
}
.navbar.sticky{
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.navbar .content{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.navbar .logo a{
  color: purple;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar .menu-list{
  display: inline-flex;
}
.menu-list li{
  list-style: none;
}
.menu-list li a{
  color: purple;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-left: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.menu-list li a:hover{
  color: orange;
  background-color: purple;
}
.logo:hover{
  background-color: orange;
}
.banner{
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
.about{
  padding: 30px 0;
}
.about .title{
  font-size: 38px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.about p{
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
}
.icon{
  color: purple;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}
.menu-list .cancel-btn{
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 20px;
}
@media (max-width: 1230px) {
  .content{
    padding: 0 60px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1100px) {
  .content{
    padding: 0 40px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .content{
    padding: 0 30px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 868px) {
  body.disabled{
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .icon{
    display: block;
  }
  .icon.hide{
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar .menu-list{
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    left: -100%;
    top: 0px;
    display: block;
    padding: 40px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: yellow;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
  .navbar.show .menu-list{
    left: 0%;
  }
  .navbar .menu-list li{
    margin-top: 45px;
  }
  .navbar .menu-list li a{
    font-size: 23px;
    margin-left: -100%;
    transition: 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  }
  .navbar.show .menu-list li a{
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 380px) {
  .navbar .logo a{
    font-size: 27px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 380px) {
  .aboutustext {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -225px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 380px) {
  .tlogo {
    position: relative;
    right: -300px;
    left: -10px;
  } 
}
.tlogo {
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  left: -350px;
}
.carbg {
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  right: -400px;
}
@media (max-width: 380px) {
  .tlogo {
    position: relative;
    right: -400px
  }
}
/* Style the buttons */
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background-color: yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: purple;
}

/* Style the active class, and buttons on mouse-over */
.active, .thebar:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: purple;
}
#myBtn {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Fixed/sticky position */
  bottom: 20px; /* Place the button at the bottom of the page */
  right: 30px; /* Place the button 30px from the right */
  z-index: 99; /* Make sure it does not overlap */
  border: none; /* Remove borders */
  outline: none; /* Remove outline */
  background-color: yellow; /* Set a background color */
  color: purple; /* Text color */
  cursor: pointer; /* Add a mouse pointer on hover */
  padding: 15px; /* Some padding */
  border-radius: 10px; /* Rounded corners */
  font-size: 18px; /* Increase font size */
}

#myBtn:hover {
  background-color: orange; /* Add a dark-grey background on hover */
}
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  background-color: #5518AB;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: "Roboto"

}

body {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro"
}
```

Comment: You can look into `intersection observer`

Comment: Sorry, I am not pro in html and css thus not knowing what that is

Comment: `Intersection observer` is something used in javascript that detects if an element is in the viewport, which then allows you to do something when that element is or isn't in the viewport. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

Comment: At what part of the page do you want your button to change?

Comment: When I am on a section in the navbar

Comment: You want it to change when hovering over your navbar?

Comment: NO I want it to change when I am on the section of the webpage for example if I am on the Members Page then I want the Members button in the navbar to change bg color and font color

Comment: [This](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/07/dynamic-header-intersection-observer/) is an example with intersection observer

Comment: Alright so if you don’t mind can you use my code and implement this function of JavaScript into it please

Comment: Please respond!

Comment: I’m sorry, am on vacation.. will be back sunday

Comment: ok sure any help is really appreciated and don't worry about my question enjoy ur vacation :) :). But pls do help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a style based on the body class. If you're on the Home page for example, you might see `<body class="home">` and then you can create a style like

```
body.home button {
  background-image: ...;
  color: #fff;
}
```